# How to set a font size for particular column in Vaadin Table?

Tags: vaadin

I have created Table using vaadin.Now i want to set font size for particular column content in that table.Is it possible to set font size for particular column in that table?.
If so please give me idea to set the font size.If u can provide me some code snippet.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, with CellStyleGenarators. Check [5.12.2 in the Book of Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html). You basically do a

```
if(propertyId.equals(yourColumnName)) { 
  return "someStyleName";
} 
else {
  return null;
}
```

inside your Table.CellStyleGenerator() and set the style for your text in css.

Answer (score 1):

using CellStyleGenerator

> ```
> simpleTable.setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
>         @Override
>         public String getStyle(Table components, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
>             int row = Integer.valueOf((String)itemId);
>             if (row%2 == 0)
>                 return "grey";
>             else
>                 return "white";
>         }
>         });
> ```

ColumnGenerator as it is described in [How to get started with Vaadin: Table Styling](http://sashcant.com/How-to-get-started-with-Vaadin_Table-Styling)

> public class DescriptionColumnGenerator implements
>   Table.ColumnGenerator {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public Object generateCell(Table components, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
>     int row = Integer.valueOf((String)itemId);
>     Property prop = components.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
>     Label label = new Label("desc: " + prop.getValue());
>
>     if (row%2 != 0) {
>         label.addStyleName("column-description");
>         label.addStyleName("column-" + (String) columnId);
>     }
>     return label;
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style name for this column.